# Pop up in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup

hello how do i create a pop up and how can i set the size etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript like this:

```
window.open("whatever.aspx", "window_name", "width=500,height=500")
```

Comment: That isnt really a modal popup. It is a whole new window.

Comment: This is also a good suggestion, if the purpose of your popup is to show another url with little to no interaction between the windows.

Comment: I would reply, but KP already made my point, so I guess I don't need to say anything.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options. I'd suggest going with an existing popup control, such as:

- [ASP.NET AJAX Popup extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) (free)
- [Telerik RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/window.aspx) (commercial but good)

You could also consider tying in clientside modal windows, such as the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), which may work well if you're using ajax.

Comment: the jquery BlockUI plugin is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 1):

What you could also always do is not "Create" a new popup window but using some CSS, you can show an overlay  and show a window like . Which is what lightbox does.

See [Create a Lightbox effect with CSS](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/)